# How to derive the loop invariant?

Tags: loops, loop-invariant

Given the following code fragment, where x is a number.

```
{ y >= 0 }
z = 0
n = y
while (n > 0) begin
z = z + x
n = n – 1
end
```

What does it compute? Prove it, showing how you derive the loop invariant.

How can I do that please?

Comment: I guess that it computes the sum of a number, like the factoriel but with the sum no? For the part of the loop invariant I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

This example is known like most correct program, because it is proved in every software verification course. Here is listing of the program with invariants on every step:

`{ y >= 0 }
    z = 0 // invariant: z = 0
    n = y // invariant: n = y and z = 0
    while (n > 0) begin // loop invariant: y * x - n * x = z
    z = z + x 
    n = n – 1
    end
    // Final invariant: n = 0 and y * x = z`

All theoretical details for this example are provided in [my paper page 118](http://www.foibg.com/ijita/vol20/ijita20-02-p02.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For given `X` and `Y` it computes `X * Y`.

at the beginning, value of the `Z` is zero, and the `N = Y` (loop's variable which will countdown in our loop).

the loop executes `Y` times and in every time that it executes, it accumulates the `X` to the `Z`.

finally, when the `N` reached to 0 the loop will terminate, then the value of `Z` should be `X * Y`.

Comment: Thanks but do you know how to show it by deriving the loop invariant please?